# Disable score in lucene to speed up search

Tags: search, lucene, information-retrieval

Currently I'm using lucene, the version is 4.10.3.

But I don't care the score and weight in search, I just need the documents meets the query. So I just want the posting list to be returned to speed up the search.

I tried some way to ignore the score, like rewrite `TermQuery`, disable the TermWeight and TermScore. It works, the search speeded up a lot, but there are too many queries to rewrite, and this is incompatible with `QueryParser`.

Also I tried `ConstantScoreQuery` and tried to rewrite `ConstantScoreQuery`, but failed. It seems that `ConstantScoreQuery` use the Weight and Score of the Query it wrapped, like `TermWeight` and `TermScorer`, so it can't speed up the search, because the weight and score is still calculated. Maybe I made it wrong, but I did some test, the search time of `new ConstantScoreQuery(new TermQuery())` is the same as `new TermQuery()`.

And i tried to rewrite the collector to replace `TopScoreCollector`,  but socre and weight is still calcaulated, the new collector won't speed up too much.

So is there any way to totally disable score in search to speed up the search. I think rewriting `ConstantScoreQuery` may work, make it `TrueConstantScoreQuery` and wraps other queries, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried the QueryWrapperFilter?

Comment: Anybody meets the same problem.

Comment: I studied the code of ConstantScoreQuery (version 4.6.1) and I think it must work. Are your really sure that you've done everything correct?

Comment: OK, i'll look into ConstantScoreQuery .